# Учебники по GCC Inline Assembler

Tags: gcc, ассемблер, книги, c++, g++

Дайте, плз, учебники по ассемблеру (gcc inline assembler).
Желательно на русском.

Answer (score 1):

Из доступного видел только такую книгу:
 С. Зубков - Assembler для DOS, Windows и UNIX
При этом про gcc и gas там только одна глава.
Поэтому рекомендую пользоваться онлайн-материалами.

Answer (score 1):

Для начала стоит овладеть GAS как таковым. Можно посмотреть [здесь](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B2_Linux_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_C)

Про встроенный ассемблер - хорошее [руководство](http://www.ibiblio.org/gferg/ldp/GCC-Inline-Assembly-HOWTO.html), но по-английски