# Изучаем Ассамблер

Tags: ассемблер

С чего начать изучать ассамблер? Желательно в линексе. Нужны советы бывалых. Что нужно знать? и с чего начать изучение?

Comment: <a href="http://linex.su/">Линекс</a>

Comment: @Sh4dow это к чему? :)

Comment: А к тому, что начинайте писать грамотно.

Answer (score 2):

В линуксе несколько ассемблеров. Основные: NASM, FASM, GAS. Первые два используют синтаксис Intel, gas - синтаксис AT&T, которые достаточно сильно отличаются. Начать лучше всего, наверное, с NASM, поскольку, на мой взгляд,синтаксис Intel несколько проще, существуют несколько хороших книжек и, к тому же, он очень схож с принятым в виндовс MASM, книг по которому куча и к которым вполне можно в случае чего обратиться. 
Но и gas тоже нельзя обойти, поскольку в него по умолчанию транслирует код gcc  и он используется в качестве инлайн-ассемблера в нем.

Источники по NASM ищи [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/35654/%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80-%D0%B2-linux?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#35667).
Кроме того, еще имеется хорошее [официальное руководство](http://www.nasm.us/doc/nasmdoc0.html). Есть русский перевод старого варианта, но лучше читай по-английски. 
По gas смотри [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/36798/%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%B1%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE-gcc-inline-assembler?%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0=1#37011).

Answer (score 0):

Ну и вопросы пошли, напиши "Хелло ворд", выучи синтаксис и вперед

[тут из вики-учебника](http://ru.wikibooks.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B5%D1%80_%D0%B2_Linux_%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BC%D0%BC%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2_C)